# Hibernate: inserting an entity with custom id in the case: strategy = GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: java, hibernate, generated

Hib just ignoring an id setting if that strategy take a place.

Are there any ways to avoid that and save the strategy?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
     return id;
}
```

...

```
Account account = new Account();
account.setId(1000L);
account.setSmth(smth);
...
//Tried to do so, but tomcat hangs on this string. 
session.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE account AUTO_INCREMENT = " + account.getId() + ";").executeUpdate();
session.save(account);
...
```

Spasibo!

Answer (score 1):

You can store entities with assigned id if necessary using this strategy:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy="org.hibernate.id.Assigned")
public Long getId() {
    ...
}
```

The only drawback is that you have to include a version field that Hibernate needs to recognize if it is a new or an existing entity:

```
@Version
public Long getVersion() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the annotation of GeneratedValue as below, then entity will use the asssigned id value. it works in my webapp.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the annotation @GeneratedValue. Hibernate will use the identifier you assigned. please see below description coming from Hibernate document.

**assigned**

**lets the application assign an identifier to the object before save() is called. This is the default strategy if no  element is specified.**

refer to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html